# coredns connection refused error while setting up kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I've got a kubernetes cluster set up with kubeadm. I haven't deployed any pods yet, but the coredns pods are stuck in a ContainerCreating status.

```
[root@master-node ~]# kubectl get -A pods
NAMESPACE     NAME                                  READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-64897985d-f5kjh               0/1     ContainerCreating   0          151m
kube-system   coredns-64897985d-xz9nt               0/1     ContainerCreating   0          151m
[...]
```

When I check it out with `kubectl describe` I see this:

```
[root@master-node ~]# kubectl describe -n kube-system pod coredns-64897985d-f5kjh
[...]
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                  ----     -------
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  22m (x570 over 145m)  kubelet  (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "4974dadd11fecf1ebfbcccd75701641b752426808889895672f34e6934776207": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/4974dadd11fecf1ebfbcccd75701641b752426808889895672f34e6934776207": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                   kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "bce2558b24468c0d0e83fe1eedf2fa70108420a466d000b74ceaf351e595007d": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/bce2558b24468c0d0e83fe1eedf2fa70108420a466d000b74ceaf351e595007d": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                   kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "e53e79bc3642c9a0c2b240dc174931af9f5dddf7d5b7df50382fcb3fea351df9": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/e53e79bc3642c9a0c2b240dc174931af9f5dddf7d5b7df50382fcb3fea351df9": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                   kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "b6da6e72057c3b48ac6ced3ba6b81917111e94c20216b65126a2733462139ed1": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/b6da6e72057c3b48ac6ced3ba6b81917111e94c20216b65126a2733462139ed1": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  18m                   kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "09416534b75ef7beea279f9389eb1a732b6a288c3b170a489e04cce01c294fa2": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/09416534b75ef7beea279f9389eb1a732b6a288c3b170a489e04cce01c294fa2": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  17m                   kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "411fe06179ab24a3999b1c034bc99452d99249bbb6cb966b496f7a8b467e1806": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/411fe06179ab24a3999b1c034bc99452d99249bbb6cb966b496f7a8b467e1806": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  17m                   kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "e0fc2a5d4852cd31eca4b473f614cadcb9235a2a325c01b469110bfd6bbf9a3b": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/e0fc2a5d4852cd31eca4b473f614cadcb9235a2a325c01b469110bfd6bbf9a3b": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  17m                   kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "4528997239e55f7ef546c0af9cc7c12cf5fe4942a370ed2a772ba7fc405773d2": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/4528997239e55f7ef546c0af9cc7c12cf5fe4942a370ed2a772ba7fc405773d2": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  17m                   kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "b534273b4fe3b893cdeac05555e47429bc7578c1e0c0095481fe155637f0c4ae": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/b534273b4fe3b893cdeac05555e47429bc7578c1e0c0095481fe155637f0c4ae": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  17m                   kubelet  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "afc479a4bfa16cef4367ecfee74333dfa9bbf12c59995446792f22c8e39ca16d": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/afc479a4bfa16cef4367ecfee74333dfa9bbf12c59995446792f22c8e39ca16d": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  3m50s (x61 over 16m)  kubelet  (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "a9254528ba611403a9b2293a2201c8758ff4adf75fd4a1d2b9690d15446cc92a": unable to allocate IP address: Post "http://127.0.0.1:6784/ip/a9254528ba611403a9b2293a2201c8758ff4adf75fd4a1d2b9690d15446cc92a": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6784: connect: connection refused
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a firewall issue. I was using Weavenet as my CNI, which requires port 6784 to be open to work. You can see this in the error, where it's trying to access 127.0.0.1:6784 and getting the connection refused (pretty obvious in hindsight). I fixed it by opening port 6784 on my firewall. For firewalld, I did

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=6784/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

This might be a security problem. The weavenet docs said something about how this port should only be accessible to certain processes or something, not sure. For my application security isn't a big concern so I didn't bother looking into it.